# plugin ajax to external php file always return null

Tags: plugins, ajax, wpdb

I am struggling with this error for a while now.

The plugin inserts data to the table.

Here's the code :

File : plugin/_add.php

```
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');

global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'westpac_store';
$result = $wpdb->insert( 
        $table_name, 
        array(  
                'itemModel' => $_POST['itemModel'], 
                'itemCat' => $_POST['itemCat'],
                'itemManu' => $_POST['itemManu'], 
                'itemImg' => $_POST['itemSpec'], 
                'itemSpec' => $_POST['itemDesc'], 
                'itemDesc' => $_POST['itemImg'], 
                'itemPrice' => $_POST['itemPrice'], 
                'itemPriceDiscount' => $_POST['itemDiscount'], 
        )
);

return ( $result == true ? 'success' : 'error' );
```

File : plugin/_common.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    //Add Item Submit
    jQuery(document).on('submit','#westpac-store-add',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var $form = jQuery(this);
        // let's select and cache all the fields
        var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
        // serialize the data in the form
        var itemData = $form.serialize();

        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

        jQuery.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: store.directory + '_add.php',
            data: itemData,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert(data.error + 'error');
            }
        });

        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });
});
```

Facts:
1. the `_add.php` is not the main plugin file.
2. its an admin interface.
3. the plugin works, the data saves in the database unless there is a data type mismatch from the input and in the database.

Problem is I can't get the actual `return` value from `_add.php`, the console.log(data) always return `""` even though the `return` in `_add.php` is fixed with string returns.
It should be at least any of the string 'success' or 'error'.

Please help!

Comment: Generally just use the WordPress way of doing AJAX as described at the codex article [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Comment: that doesnt solve the problem and evaded it

Comment: Never claimed that it will solve you problem. Just telling you that your life will be easier if you do it that way.

Comment: actually I used that documentation to produce the external ajaxing, everything works just the return thing. although I manage to figure it out.

Comment: Good for you. It still is better to do it different, but do as you like. I just wanted to give you that hint.

Comment: But you only used part and ignored the rest. If this is to be released as a .org plugin, it will be rejected for doing ajax incorrectly.

Comment: thanks for the concern ialocin & Milo, don't worry this will never will never go .org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it

instead of using

```
return ( $result == true ? 'success' : 'error' );
```

use

```
echo ( $result == true ? 'success' : 'error' );
```